# RadioButtonList in GridView returns incorrect value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList inside a GridView on an ASP.Net webpage. I'm unable to get the SelectedValue in the code behind. The RadioButtonList looks like this:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDataInfo" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reimbursement Validation">
                        <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEligible" Text='<%# Eval("MonthlyServiceEligible") %>'></asp:Label><asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblDataMonthlyServiceEligible" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("MonthlyServiceEligible") %>'>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" />
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" />
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
RadioButtonList rblEligible = new RadioButtonList();
        bool Eligible = false;
        if (LastDataRowNumber >= 0)
        {
            rblEligible = (RadioButtonList)gvDataInfo.Rows[LastDataRowNumber].FindControl("rblDataMonthlyServiceEligible");
            if (rblEligible.SelectedValue != null)
                Eligible = Convert.ToBoolean(rblEligible.SelectedValue);
        }
```

There are a number of other controls in the GridView, but I only show the RadioButtonList for simplicity's sake. LastDataRowNumber is set programmatically and is correct. I can verify its value via the debugger and can correctly get the values of other controls in the GridView for this row. However, the RadioButtonList.SelectedValue is always set to "True" in the code behind, no matter what I set it to on the client. What am I missing?

Comment: question.. are you doing and `IsPostBack` checking.. sounds like a a Postback issue in regards to you losing values

Comment: No, I'm not checking, but I am able to retrieve correctly all the values of the other controls in the GridView. Just this radiobuttonlist is giving me a problem.